# Why will byte not take 0xff in java?

Tags: java, byte

Why will java compiler not let me put `0xff` into a `byte`, `0xff` is 8 bits long which is just the size of `byte` datatype.

 *Can someone explain why 1 works and why 2 does not ?*

```
class a
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                // 1 :: results in error
                byte a = 0xff;          
                System.out.printf("%x\n",a);

                //2 :: works fine
                byte a = (int)0xff              
                System.out.printf("%x\n",a);
        }
}
```

**EDIT** I read the answer claiming that 0xff is 255, how so ? Is it not `1111 1111`, What makes 0xff, -128 or 255 or anything for that matter. Why will it not just treat it as `1111 1111` and not the 8 bits of that byte to 1.

Comment: neither of these work

Comment: see the docs for [primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in java

Comment: In Java, a byte is restricted to -128 to 127 because it is considered a signed primitive. You cannot cast an integer into a byte because primitives can only move up in hierarchy, not down.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Java `byte` type is an 8 bit signed integral type with values in the range `-128` to `+127`.  The literal `0xff` represents `+255` which is outside of that range.

In the first example, you are attempting to assign a value that is out of range to a `byte`.  That is a compilation error.

In the second example, the `(byte)` cast is performing an explicit narrowing conversion, that removes the high order bits of the integer literal ... giving you the value `-127` in your `byte` variable.

---

In fact, the situation with the first example is a bit more complicated than that.  Consider this:

```
byte a = 1;         // OK
int i = 1;
byte b = i;         // Compilation error
byte c = (byte) i;  // OK
```

Under normal circumstances, you cannot assign an `int` to a `byte` without a cast.  However, if the value are assigning is a literal, and the literal value is within the range of the target type, the Java language permits the assignment *without* a cast.  The literal's value is implicitly narrowed from `int` to `byte`.

This is described in [JLS §5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) which defines the conversions that may be performed in an assignment:

> *"A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable."*

And as you can see, this doesn't *just* apply to literals.  It applies to all (compile-time) constant expressions!

---

**FOLLOW-UP**

> I read the answer claiming that `0xff` is `255`, how so? Is it not `1111 1111`, What makes `0xff`, `-128` or `255` or anything for that matter?

The literal `0xff` is an *integer literal*.  It has type `int`.  The `int` value of the literal `0xff` is actually `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111` in binary or +255 in decimal.  By contrast, the integer value `-128` has the bit pattern `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000`.

> Why will it not just treat it as `1111 1111` and not the 8 bits of that byte to 1?

Because `0xff` is an *integer literal*; i.e. 32 bits.  It is not an 8-bit literal, because 8-bit literals do not exist in Java.  As [JLS §3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says:

> *"An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1))."*

Answer (score 16):

`0xff` is a [hexadecimal representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) of a number. In other words the number is base 16.

`f = 15` in hex.

The value is equal to

```
15 * 16^1 + 15 * 16^0 = 255
```

This is an [integer literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) (uses 4 bytes), which exceeds `byte`'s value range.

Neither of the two examples you've posted will compile as neither fits into `byte`'s value range of `-128 to 127`. You can read about primitive type value ranges [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

This will work

```
byte a = (byte)0xff; 
System.out.println(a);
```

and print `-1`, because a byte narrowing conversion of `255` is `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

`0xff` is 255. While this does fit into an 8-bit *unsigned* integer, `byte` is signed(-128 to 127). The narrowing will remove the high bits and fit 8 into 8 without regard for sign.

Comment: the `(-128 to 127)` is in the wrong place of your phrase. those are actually signed values.

Answer (score 4):

First, if I try to run your code, the 2. case doesn't work either. You cast 0xff to the primitive datatype int (which has 32 bit) and want to store it in a 'byte' with only 8bit. Java treats your first case as int too, resulting in the same problem.

Because the java 'byte' type is an 8-bit signed integer value (from -128 to 127), to output / print the byte as hex, you can use Integer.toHexString('the primitive byte' & 0xFF) where ' & 0xFF ' is a bitmask to take into account that Integer uses a 32bit int and byte uses 8bit.

```
    byte myByte = (byte)0xff;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(myByte & 0xFF));
```

This outputs:

```
ff
```