# String to byte[] in java without converting

Tags: android

hi my function return String which is already in bytes for example

```
String ss = Long.toHexString(checksum);
return ss;
```

now the String ss return results in bytes;

```
result is = ff32ge34
```

this is crc32 checksum

now in next method i want to use this string in byte[]

for example

byte[] any = ss;

but as ss is String so error is coming but actually ss String is checksum in bytes so any way i can use this string in byte[] ?

i want it this way

```
byte[] any = new byte[]{0xff ,0x32 ,0xge,0x34};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to convert the original long to byte array. It is simpler and much faster than converting a String to byte array

```
public byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte) (value >> 56),
        (byte) (value >> 48),
        (byte) (value >> 40),
        (byte) (value >> 32),
        (byte) (value >> 24),
        (byte) (value >> 16),
        (byte) (value >> 8),
        (byte) value
    };
}
```

But if you insist in converting a String into byte array, you can use something like this

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len/2];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
        data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
     }

    return data;
}
```

But as you can see, it's ugly and much slower than converting a long to byte array.

You can use this function to reverse the order of a byte array

```
public static void reverse(byte[] data) {
    for (int left = 0, right = data.length - 1; left < right; left++, right--) {
        // swap the values at the left and right indices
        byte temp = data[left];
        data[left]  = data[right];
        data[right] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnot fit in this byte[] any = new byte[]{0xff ,0x32 ,0xge,0x34};  even i use long as return the output is different

Comment: It is like that, only when you are debugging you see it differently because byte in java goes -127 to 127 and 0xFF is beyond that so you are likely seeing a negative -1 See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812864/why-will-byte-not-take-0xff-in-java

Comment: thanks now it works checked as answer thats what i wanted to keep things easy not complex :)

Comment: i have one question more for you what if i want to reverse this new byte  like 0x44,0x22 and make it 0x22,0x44 something like that ?

Comment: change the order of bit shift operations in the function so that value >> 56 is last and value is first and you will effectively turned around the byte array. Also if you don't need a byte array of 8 bytes, you can only use the first 4 bit shifts

Comment: reverse it when using  hexStringToByteArray not longtobytearray function ?

Comment: no no i mean, i used your method   byte[] new = hexStringToByteArray(mm); which i used in  byte[] Bytes1 = new;  but now can this be reversed without using longToByteArray and by using this hexStringToByteArray

Comment: Just use ArrayUtils.reverse(byteArr); to reverse it.

Comment: ArrayUtils can not be resolved ,is this class ? where is source

Comment: or could you modify this                                                                   public byte[] reverse3(byte[] nums) {
        byte[] values = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = nums.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                values[i] = nums[j];
            }
        }
        return values;
    }

Comment: done this one work but it would be helpful for someone if you could add return data; in the reverse cus it is void and many would use that data to do further operations :)

Comment: hi now i get this error in your this function please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334283/caused-by-java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-length-7-index-7-android