# Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7 Android java

Tags: java, android

Hi i use function to hex string to byte array and it gives me this error sometimes it works some times it gives error

> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7;index=7    > at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
>   at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494)

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len/2];

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
         }

        return data;
    }
```

error comes in this code and
why it works most of the time and only sometimes it makes application force close,can anybody fix this so that it can work always

i use this function above to make crc32 checsum to bytearray

here is the function i use to get crc32 checsum

```
private String chesum() {

        String fileName = "file.bin";

        try {

            CheckedInputStream cis = null;

            try {
                // Compute CRC32 checksum
                cis = new CheckedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(fileName), new CRC32());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found.");

            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[128];
            while(cis.read(buf) >= 0) {
            }

            long checksum = cis.getChecksum().getValue();

            String ss = Long.toHexString(checksum);

            cis.close();
            return ss;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;


    }
```

after this method i call hexstringtobytearray function

Comment: I think it throws error when ever the length is an ODD NUMBER, so check the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < len-1 ; i+=2){
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
         }
```

Change the condition  `len` to `len -1`

Comment: this actually make it works but the hexstring to byte array is not the answer it should be without -1 asnwer is perfect but it force close

Comment: That's because your input is incorrect. You are tryin to convert the string by taking two characters at a time and converting them to a byte. If you take two characters at a time, the input should contain an even number of characters.

However, the length of your input is odd (7, in the example exception you gave). What should you do in case of an odd-length inputstring? Discard the last character? Pad the string with a null byte? You should handle that in your for-loop or after the loop.

Comment: @Buurman yes thats the problem works with even could you plz try modify it and post the answer in code as you know i am android starter i make mistakes and learn thank you so much :)

Comment: @androidstarter: What should be done with a string of odd length? If we don't know, we can't help you with that. ;-)