# What happened to the byte 0xFF (11111111) in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, bit, bitwise-operators

I need to send the byte 0xFF to a client, but when I do this:

```
byte toSend = 0b11111111;
// or
byte toSend = 0xFF;
```

I get a compile error sending it can't convert from int to byte.

I want to make sure I am sending a byte with all 8 bits set to 1. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: byte toSend = -1 will do the trick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812864/why-will-byte-not-take-0xff-in-java?rq=1

Comment: 0xff is an integer literal, hence the compile error. Also, the fact that byte is signed has nothing to do; binary-wise, 11111111 is 11111111.

Comment: @fge So who do i send 11111111 ????

Comment: Well, @Eran gives you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to byte :

```
byte toSend = (byte)0xFF;
```

Forget the other part of my answer. I'm a bit sleep deprived. Actually it's -1 that is represented as 11111111. But `(byte)0xFF` works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure it will be sent as 1111 1111 to the other side?

Comment: @PeterMel yes. The reason it doesn't work without the cast is that 0xFF is 255, and the range of byte is from -128 to 127.

Comment: @Eran I think you mean `-1` and not `-128`.

Comment: @AlexisC. Yes, thanks. It gets hard to think straight with not enough sleep :)